# What are the ports that should be open between Deployment Manager and Application Servers?

Tags: ibm, websphere, application-server

I install Deployment Manager and Application Server on different servers each one exist on different zone as following :

1- Deployment Manager : Web Zone .

2- Application Server : App Zone .

What are that ports should be open it between these two zone ?

Comment: butchberlemann's answer links to the ports already, but I just wanted to add that you also need to make sure you open the ports for the Node Agents, not just the Application Servers.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what version of WAS your running but here is a listing of the 6.1 ports [Port number settings in WebSphere Application Server versions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rmig_portnumber.html).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault - [we generally prefer answers that have more content than just a link somewhere else, so that if the link ever disappears the answer is still valuable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231). Could you please improve your answer by listing the most common/useful WebSphere ports here?

Comment: voretaq7 you must not work with IBM products much, just finding a useful link is a huge help.

Comment: Actually I've got pretty extensive experience with IBM products. I've also got extensive experience with the "useful link" disappearing. Again: Please read the post I linked to and consider revising your answer to be useful when the link goes away.

Comment: I'm Using version 7.0